# Pointer of class to void*

Tags: c++, class, pointers, void-pointers

i am working on a rpg games with class
i created a struct call Character with ActionList* which store the instance.
GeneralPlayer is a class where there have still a bunch of other players classes inherited it.
This is my header file:

```
class Battle
{
public:
       struct Character
      {
        char type;//monster or player?
        bool alive;
        void*instance;//pointer to instance
      };
      Battle(GeneralPlayer*,AbstractMonster*,int,int,int);     
      Battle(GeneralPlayer*, AbstractMonster*, int, int);
private:
       Character *ActionList;
};
```

i was trying to convert GeneralPlayer* to void*. However seems like the code doesnt work as i thought. P and M are array of pointers of those player classes.

```
 Battle::Battle(GeneralPlayer*P, AbstractMonster*M, int a, int b, int c)
{
   a = numP;
   b = numM;
   c = turn_limit;
   ActionList = new Character[numP + numM];
   P = new GeneralPlayer[numP];
   for (int i = 0; i < numP; i++)
   { 
      ActionList[i] = static_cast<void*>(P[i]);
      ActionList[i].type = 'p';
   }
  for (int i = numP; i < numP+numM; i++)
  {
      ActionList[i] = static_cast<void*>(M[i]);
      ActionList[i].type = 'm';
  }
}
```

it keeps showing the error C2440. I wish can solve my problem with anyone helps thank you.

Comment: `P[i]` is not a `GeneralPlayer*`, it's a `GeneralPlayer`.

Comment: Do you mean that after you called the function, the variable you passed as `P` doesn't seem to be initialized? Please try to elaborate, and also please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: @songyuanyao sorry i am still beginner. if P[i] isnt GeneralPlayer*, then what should i suppose to use?

Comment: If my above comment isn't the problem (yet), and if you have e.g. build errors, then please edit the question to include the complete and unedited build-log. If you haven't done so yet, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You **never** need a `static_cast` to conver a pointer to anything to `void*`. This conversion happens automatically.

Comment: Something else besides your actual problem, since nobody told you: Arrays in C++ are evil. Try to avoid them whenever possible. Use vectors instead. You don't need to give number of entries as parameters if you do so, vector has size() for that. Will save you from a bunch of pointer arithmetic errors.

Comment: Arrays not evil. Raw pointers to dynamically allocated arrays are evil. Simple rule of thumb: If you don't know the size at compile time, use a `std::vector`. Otherwise use an array or `std::array` depending on your needs. For example, `std::array` is much easier to pass around than an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the problems here is that the `Character` structure is not a parent of either `GenericPlayer` or `AbstractMonster`. It seems that the `Character::instance` member should be pointing to the player or monster, which means your code should be something like

```
ActionList[i].type = 'p';
ActionList[i].alive = true;
ActionList[i].instance = &P[i];
```

This is assuming that the list of players is already initialized by the caller of the `Battle` constructor, then you should not allocate a new array of players, so the `P = new GenericPlayer[numP];` statement should be removed.

It should be noted that having something like you do, a "generic pointer" (what `void *` is) and then a member saying what type it's really pointing to is considered bad design. Instead you would have a common base-class for both monsters and players, and use a pointer to that. Then with the correct use of *polymorphism* and `virtual` member functions you don't need the `type` field. And then it's easy to refactor the code to use some other means of telling if a player or monster is alive or not, and then you don't need the `Battle::Character` class at all, and could use an array of pointers to the common base class instead, thus simplifying the code a bit, which is very good for maintainability.

---

There are a few other problems with the code as you show it, things that will cause problems later at runtime.

One problem is that in the loop iterating over the monsters, you initialize `o` to `numP` and loop up to `numP + numM`, but if the array `M` doesn't contain `numP + numM` elements you will go out of bounds.

Instead I suggest you do e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numM; i++)
{ 
    ActionList[i + numP].type = 'm';
    ActionList[i + numP].alive = true;
    ActionList[i + numP].instance = &M[i];
}
```

Comment: @ShiYiLee Lets assume you have a function `void f(int a) { a += 5; }`. Now when you call the function, say `f(some_int_variable)`, would you expect `some_int_variable` to change? It's the same thing here with your pointer variable `P` in the `Battle` constructor function, inside the function `P` is a *local* variable, all modifications to `P` will only be local inside the function. When you assign to `P` (`P = new ...`) then it's only inside the function, the variable you use in the call will not be modified.

Comment: @ShiYiLee The problem discussed in my previous comment is solved by passing `P` by reference, the change is very simple: `Battle(GenericPlayer*& P, ...)`. Adding the ampersand (`&`) there make `P` a *reference* to a pointer to `GenericPlayer`.

Comment: but now i am having another problem "a value of type"GeneralPlayer*" cannot to be assigned to an entity of type "Battle::Character*" if i followed your steps

Comment: @ShiYiLee Oh I see now that `Character` is a local type to the `Battle` class, and my assumption that `GenericPlayer` or `AbstractMonster` inherits from it is wrong. Instead you should set the `instance` member to point to the player/monsters. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to convert object into pointer, use the **&** operator to get the pointer in question.

```
ActionList[i] = (void*)&P[i];
ActionList[i] = (void*)&M[i];
```

Comment: You don't need the explicit (and even c-style) cast. Any data pointer type can be implicitly cast to `void*`

Comment: Also, Character *ActionList should maybe be of data type Character **,  Character ** ActionList = new Character*[numP + numM];

Comment: This is true, but doesn't answer the question (`ActionList[i ].instance = (void*)&P[i];` would) or solve the OP's problem. Plus why would you want to discard all of the type-checking goodness the compiler can do for you?